# How to add multiple images to a node using node.save service?

Tags: entities, services

I am using the services module along with the json server module to add a node to my drupal web site from an external application.

One of the cck fields is an image field which can accept multiple values. In my javascript application I'm calling the node.save service with node object like:

`node_obj.field_image = [{ "fid": fid }];`

This successfully adds the image value to the cck field. But how do I add another image value to this field? Calling the service again overrides the old image vale with the new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[{ "fid": 1 }, { "fid": 2 }];
```

have you tried this?